# Salario DataTables jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax, datatables

No manejo mucho el `DataTables` por el cual e intentado varias formas de poder convertir un resultado de `ajax` que son números y convertirlos en salario, pero como lo estoy manejando de una forma diferente al `DataTables` de pronto se me va la idea.

Agradeceria que pudieran resolver mi problema.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tabla_salario" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>salario</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>                                            
  </tbody>    
</table>
```

**JQUERY/AJAX:**

```
var tabla = $('#tabla_salario').DataTable({

                        "columnDefs": [
                               {
                                  "targets": [ 0 ],
                                  "visible": true
                               },   
                            ],
                         }); 


listar_datos();

function listar_datos()
{   
    $.ajax({
          url: 'listar_salario',
          type: 'POST'
        })
        .done(function(data)
        {
            var dato = $.parseJSON(data);

            for (var i = dato.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
                var rowNode = tabla
               .row.add([ dato[i].salario, ])
               .draw()
               .node();
            }
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto, espero que te sirva

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
listar_datos();

function listar_datos()
{   
 $.get('lista.php', function(data){
  if( data.success ){
   for( var $item in data.salarios ){
    console.log( $item );
    $('#tabla_salario > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+formatCurrency(data.salarios[$item])+'</td></tr>');
   }
   var tabla = $('#tabla_salario').DataTable({

    "columnDefs": [
        {
        "targets": [ 0 ],
        "visible": true
        },   
     ]
    });
  }
 },'json');
 
 
}

function formatCurrency(num) {
 num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
 if (isNaN(num))
  num = "0";
 sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
 num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
 cents = num % 100;
 num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
 if (cents < 10)
  cents = "0" + cents;
 for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
  num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + ',' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
 return ((sign) ? '' : '-') + '$' + num + '.' + cents;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css">

<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla_salario"> 
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>salario</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  
 </tbody> 
</table>
```

lista.php ->

```
<?php
    $salarios = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++){
        $salarios[] = mt_rand();
    }
    echo json_encode([ 'success' => true, 'salarios' => $salarios]);
```

Comment: el ejemplo es funcional pero depronto cometi el error de no hacerme entender; el problema es que tengo el numero "500000" y debo de convertirlo a "$500.000" con una funcion que tiene datatables pero que no la he podido entender

Comment: Edité el ejemplo con lo que creo que necesitas